# SEVERE: A child container failed during start tomcat8

Tags: java, servlet-3.0, tomcat8

I wrote a simple sevlet program. When I am trying to deploy the same in tomcat I am getting the below error.

I have tried by removing annotations.

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Trial]]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Trial]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
 ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> firstTest in servlet mapping
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3104)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3079)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1368)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1172)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:767)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5074)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 ... 6 more

Sep 19, 2014 9:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:760)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 ... 6 more

Sep 19, 2014 9:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:760)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 ... 11 more

Sep 19, 2014 9:51:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 19, 2014 9:51:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 19, 2014 9:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 19, 2014 9:51:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 19, 2014 9:51:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:795)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:531)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAcc
```

servlet code is below. the server is starting fine without the application

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
 */

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public MyServlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you see this message in the nested stacktrace?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    Invalid <url-pattern> firstTest in servlet mapping
```

It seems to be saying that you have a servlet-mapping element in your web.xml that has an invalid url-pattern.  Look for the problem in that file.

Answer (score -1):

Mistake in url pattern. Check xml file

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer?